# Mongo Export : Error parsing query as Extended JSON: cannot decode array into

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

When i ran the below aggregation query .it works fine.It returns all the `myval' field and its value .But when i am trying to run it as part of my mongoexport query i keep getting the error.

I want to store the output of query as a CSV/json file.How to fix the below error

My mongo db version is `db version v4.4.20`

```
[
 {$unwind: "$la"},
 {$unwind: "$la.pd"}, 
 {$project: { _id: 0 ,value_extract : "$la.va.myobj.myval"} }  
]
```

MOngo export query

```
 mongodump  --db mydb --collection mycollection  --queryFile q.json  --out /home/op.csv
```

Error message is

> Failed: error parsing query as Extended JSON: cannot decode array into
> a primitive.D

Answer (score 0):

You are passing an aggregation pipeline where a query filter is expected.

From the [docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/mongodump/#std-option-mongodump.--queryFile):

> --queryFile=
>
> Specifies the path to a file containing a JSON document as a query filter that limits the documents included in the output of mongodump. --queryFile enables you to create query filters that are too large to fit in your terminal's buffer.

The query filter must be a JSON document, containing [query operators](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/#query-and-projection-operators).

You can use aggregation operators in a query filter by using [$expr](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/#mongodb-query-op.-expr), but that will not permit aggregation stages such at $unwind.

What you might try is run that aggregation with an [$out](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/#-out--aggregation-) stage, storing the documents in a temporary collection.  Then use mongoexport on the temporary collection.

Comment: u mean i am getting error because of $unwind operator?

Comment: I mean mongoexport will accept a query object like you would pass to `db.collection.find` *_not_* a pipeline like you would pass to `db.collection.aggregate`

Comment: Ok.can u tell me how to get the just `la.va.myobj.myval`  using find ?

Comment: mongoexport doesn't handle expressive projections.  Your best option would be to aggregate to a temporary collection and mongoexport that temp collection.